# Installing spring security plugin in grails application

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have an application built in grails. Now I want to add security features to the application by using spring security. I have read about how to install it in new application but didn't come across a scenario where it is installed in a built application. Anybody have any idea or Link please share it here. Thanks

Comment: why do you think that there is a difference between installing into a new application and built?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to add security at the beginning, since like testing and documentation, the later you start the more work it can be to get things where they should be. But adding security to an existing application is straightforward in general.

You'll be best off to use "strict mode", e.g. deny access to all resources unless there's a rule defining access (even if that rule says that anyone can access that url). In 1.2.x that's described at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html and in 2.0 it's enabled by default and is described at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/requestMappings.html and at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/newInV2.html

Whether you use "strict mode" or not, pick one of the 3 approaches to applying security, and add annotations/database requestmaps/etc. for all of your controllers and other accessible urls, and configure other features such as SSL rules.

Be sure to test your security. This is best done with functional testing since you want to test against a real running web server.